# jQuery dialog fires on page load, trying to make it on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog, modal-dialog

this is my code:

```
    $('#delete_me').click(openDialog());

    function openDialog(){
        $('#myDialog').dialog({
            'title': 'My Dialog Header',
            'buttons': {
                'yes': function(event) {

                }
            }
        });
    }
```

the dialog shows when the page loads and then it is working as wanted when the element is clicked, what am I doing wrong? I don't want to show the dialog when the page loaded.

EDIT:
this way the dialog shows just when clicked but disappears after 0.5 sec

```
        $('#delete_me').click(function(){openDialog();});
```

Comment: `$('#delete_me').click(openDialog);` Pass the function, don't call the function

Comment: shows and disappears immediately

Comment: what happens if you add `return false;` at the end of the `openDialog()` function ?

Comment: it shows and disappears immediately

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the function, simply remove the parentheses when you're passing openDialog.

```
$('#delete_me').click(openDialog);
```